# symfony2-easyadmin bundle blank screen error

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

i have a strange problem when trying to render entity in symfony2 easyadminBundle i got a blank screen without any errors,
when trying to list entity 'Ads' that has many-to-one relation-ship with entity 'pages' ,where page contains many ads., however if i modified the action parameter in the url to be `&action=new` instead of `&action=list` it shows the form but after saving it giving me the same blank screen!
My Pages Entity :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_name", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $pageName;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;



/*@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ads", mappedBy="pages")
 *
 */

protected $ads;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->ads = new ArrayCollection();
}    
}
```

Ads Entity:

```
/**
* Ads
*
* @ORM\Table(name="ads")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Ads
{



/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $page_id ;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ad_text", type="text", nullable=false)
 */
private $adText;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;



/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pages", inversedBy="ads")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

private $page_ad;


}
```

Comment: Your `$ads` phpdoc block does not look correct. It should start with `/**`

Comment: FTR in 2018 this issue still exists. `AppBundle\Entity\Campaign\Ad` shows a blank page, but renaming the class to `AppBundle\Entity\Campaign\Advert` works as normal. Incidentally, the network inspector shows the HTML response coming back as expected, but it isn't rendered in the window (Chrome, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks "not complicated", so it should work as expected. The "blank page" error is really strange. We render the data with `try...catch` to avoid any issue when we cannot access the information. Besides, we also catch the exceptions to display customized error pages.

Can you see any error message in your `dev.log` file?

You could also do the following. Create the simplest possible configuration for the `list` view of the `Ads` entity as follows:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Ads:
            list:
                fields: ['id']
```

If this work, try adding more fields one by one until you find the error.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't works , the strange thing is the `new,show` actions works when change to them, and there is nothing in dev_log., is there a way to debug this this ?

Comment: The best way to debug would be to add some `dump()` calls to the Twig extension which renders the information. This extension is located in `Twig/EasyAdminTwigExtension.php` file and the method is `renderEntityField()`. Try to add `dump($entityConfiguration, $fieldName)` in line 117 to see which information is output and then try to add more `dump()` below to see when this breaks.

Comment: In my case a blank page was presented when 1) entity is in a OneToMany relationship, and 2) included the ToMany field that has > 100K rows.  Eliminating the ToMany field restored the display.

Comment: @geoB I understand :(  I want to add an autocomplete field soon. It should fix your issue.